# Is it possible to extract consumer_secret from oauth signature?

Tags: oauth

I have a password encrypted in a DB with a hidden method. I want to use Oauth, in PLAINTEXT signature mode in order to be abble to extract the consumer_secret from the oauth_signature attribute. First is it a good idea to do that? second how can i do it if i cannot guess the lenght of the original consumer_secret.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: No, it is not a good idea. Why would you do that?

**Second**: The whole idea with secrets is that you're not supposed to be able to guess them.

If you are either an API consumer or an API provider communicating using OAuth, either party has to have full knowledge of keys and secrets from the start, otherwise the process cannot be completed. That goes for any of the signature methods.

That having been said, if you receive a request signed using the [PLAINTEXT signing method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.4), the consumer secret is in the `oauth_signature` parameter, before the `&` character.

*Edit*: If you store the secrets hashed, then you need to hash the incoming secrets in the same way before comparing and validating.

Comment: Thanks @Jon for your answer. As the password (consumer_secret) is hashed (using an obscur method) and saved in the DB, Does it imply that i cannot use OAuth, since the client doesn't know the hash of the password?

Comment: If you store the consumer secret hashed. Then hash the consumer secret that you get in requests in the same way before comparing.